# What is first, a customer journey map, personas creation or user cases?

Tags: user-behavior, user-research, personas, use-cases

I am in the beggining of a new app, and I would like to know the order of the tasks: after the questions to the users and stakeholders, what is the order? a customer journey map, personas creation or user cases?

thanks and regards,
Alejandro.

Comment: Depends on the purpose of the app, whether there is an existing app or not, and what the expected audience is. Can you add more detail?

Comment: I'd say that the first should be shadowing and observations, before (and possibly instead of) the interviews.

Comment: The project is about an app made for the coordinators of an elderly home. They have to control that the nurseries give the right meals and the right cares to the residents. So then, I think I should know the profile of them, later prepare a customer journey map to watch the life cycle of the app with the coordinators, and finally the user cases. What do you think?

Answer (score 2):

You can't define a customer journey without knowing the customer. Persona's can help to gain and share this knowledge.

Use cases are descriptions of steps to achieve something. They are very specific and therefore useful for engineeers and developers.

Before you know which exact steps users should take you need to know how you want them to experience your product or service. So creating a customer journey can help to define use cases.

In short:
1. Persona's
2. Customer journey
3. Use cases

Comment: ok, I think it could be a better order: it takes from the most general step (personas) to the most specific (user cases). Thanks!